# Relation between $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a real manifold of dimension n. Let $U, V$ be two chart domains on M such that $U \cap V$ is nonempty. Let $\varphi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $\varphi = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $\psi:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $\psi = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ be the corresponding charts. I know that the vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ form a basis of the $C^{\infty}(U)$-module $\Gamma(TU)$, so on $U \cap V$ there exists some functions $f_{ij}$ such that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} = \sum_{j=1}^n f_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$$ My question is: How can I find these functions $f_{ij}$ ? I'm pretty new in this stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You say the coordinate vector fields form a basis of the module of vector fields.
Are you familiar with the fact that
$$X=\sum_jX(x^j)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$$
for every vector field $X$?
If you are, then just take $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful comment!